# How to set window focus

Tags: android

In an android game app I have the splash screen layout with start, resume and exit buttons. From the start button I go to a surfaceview and start a worker thread from there.
I want to implement the device back button properly. When the user touches the back button, I come back to the splash screen menu. The problem is this: when I return to the splash screen, the start, resume and exit buttons don't react from user interactions anymore. It seems like they loosed focus.
How can I set the Splash Screen to have focus again?

```
public class SplashScreen extends Activity {

    ...
    ...
    ...

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.splash_screen_layout);

        this.mRoadView = (RoadView) findViewById(R.id.road_view);

        this.mStartButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start_button);
        this.mResumeButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.resume_button);
        this.mExitButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.exit_button);

        prepareButtonListeners();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (mDoubleBackPressed) {
            super.onBackPressed();
        } else {
            setContentView(R.layout.splash_screen_layout);
            mDoubleBackPressed = true;
        }
    }

    private void prepareButtonListeners() {
        this.mStartButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {            
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mDoubleBackPressed = false;
                setContentView(R.layout.road_view_layout);
            }
        });

        ...
        ...
        ...
```

Thank you very much,
Daniel.

Answer (score 0):

```
KeyEvent downEvent = new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK);

KeyEvent upEvent = new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_UP, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK);

view.dispatchTouchEvent(downEvent);

view.dispatchTouchEvent(upEvent);
```